# Is it possible To Link Object Mesh Data without changing UV mapping?

Tags: uv, linked-data

I'm planning to use multiple "hexagon style" images in my scene but this will create millions of the same hexagon object and slow down the software. So after i generate hexagon objects with my geometry nodes, i apply the mesh, do an unwrap project from view, add a material, load an image texture, and then i would like to link ONLY the mesh data of all the hexagon objects to reduce the number of faces/vertices in the scene while keeping the image as is.

[image]

But linking the mesh data also links the UV map to the same coordinates as the active object i am  linking from hence wiping out my image. I read that it is possible to have different materials for the same linked mesh by using `Link Material` To `Object` instead of `Link Material` To `Object Data`. Is this also possible for the UV mapping? Or is there another method i should employ to retain the image while having shared mesh data?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions here.

### First

Make a GN setup which will generate UV map for rendering, but keeps instances for viewport.

[image]

> it's not clear to me how you did the UV unwrapping step since i
> cannot unwrap each instance individually

I have default grid initially UV unwrapped. Then UV coordinates are transferred to instances using **Transfer Attribute** node. Last step - to make UV coordinate act like a pixel, I use **Capture Attribute** node in **Instances** mode, to make UV coordinates share per instance.

After that, I pass the resulted UV coordinate to attribute in the modifier settings:

[image]

And this attribute can be used in shader node tree as an attribute:

[image]

### 1.1

You can also pass color information instead of UV:

[image]

### Second

Use object color in material, so that object and material will be linked

[image]

But colors must be set somehow, maybe using python

Comment: thanks for your help. i tried implementing your first solution but it's not clear to me how you did the UV unwrapping step since i cannot unwrap each instance individually.

Comment: I have updated the answer.